# Error in tableau while checking accuracy of forecasted value in R

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, tableau-desktop

I am trying to check the accuracy of the forecasted values while using tableau and R
with  the below code

```
FLOAT(SCRIPT_STR(
"library(forecast);
time <- ts(.arg1,start = c(2020,11), frequency = 12);
arima_model <- auto.arima((time),approximation= TRUE,trace=TRUE);
forecasted <- forecast(arima_model);
paste(fitted(forecasted(time))
",AVG([Enterprise Health Score])))
```

But getting the below mentioned error

Error in base::parse(text = .cmd) : :7:0: unexpected end of input 5: paste(fitted(forecasted(time)) 6: ^

Comment: @ jon spring i have checked that is not an issue the calculation shows valid

Comment: Does it work if you put the endquote at the end of the `paste` line?